# How to count different data on the basis of date for distinct users in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following schema :

**Table T**

```
|ITEM_ID|   |USER_ID|  | DUE_DATE  |
    1           1        2018-01-2
    1           1        2018-01-2
    1           1        2018-01-3
    1           2        2018-01-2
    2           1        2018-01-2
    2           2        2018-01-2
```

What I want is to get the count of actions performed by a unique user on that particular day, one week.

This is the select query which I'm using however it does not takes care of the fact about unique user.

```
select ITEM_ID,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end) as today,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= cast(getdate() - 7 as date) then 1 else 0 end) as week,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) then 1 else 0 end) as month
from t
group by ITEM_ID;
```

How can I the select count of actions performed by a unique user on that particular day, one week.

For example : let's suppose today is 2018-01-2

So the expected result should be :

```
ITEM_ID, COUNT_TODAY, COUNT_TOMORROW
1         2              1   
2         1              1
```

What I need is the unique user performing the transaction of that particular item type for that day.

That is in the above example, the user having id 1 performed the **transaction of** **type 1** 2 times on **2018-01-2.** So it should be counted as 1 instead of 2.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show us your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want.

```
select USER_ID, ITEM_ID,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end) as today,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= cast(getdate() - 7 as date) then 1 else 0 end) as week,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) then 1 else 0 end) as month
from t
group by USER_ID, ITEM_ID;
```

Comment: I need to group by item_id

Comment: @Paras If you dont need the USER_ID delete the USER_ID from the select part but not from the GROUP BY part

Comment: @Paras I think I dont understand what do you want. What do you mean by  particular day, one week. This has no meaning.

Comment: If a user having id 1 performed the transaction of type 1 two times on 2018-01-2. So it should be counted as 1 instead of 2. Currently it does not.

Comment: @Paras You are saying to different things up in your question you say my expected result should be 2 no you say in should be 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163773/discussion-between-paras-and-andam).